# How to troubleshoot Push Notifications module

Tags: services

I'm trying to get the [Push Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/push_notifications) module to work correctly. So far I have successfully gotten my device to register with the service, and now I am trying to test the push back to APN. I went through [This](http://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/) entire process and created the .pem file from my certification. When I attempt to test the push, I get the following error

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed, or how to further troubleshoot. I've tried looking up the error but the definitions seem vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be my own error, I was using the wrong certificate, one that was not set up for push notifications, otherwise, everything works just like the instructions.

Comment: heh, was just typing up that it's a certificate issue!  And glad to see that you posted the "fix"!

Comment: also "**ssl://**" need to be installed on your server if you are using ubuntu 12.04 server you should runt $ sudo apt-get install sslh -y Regards